# Java EE CDI - obtaining a new instance of a class each time a method is called

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I am looking to do some refactoring of a Java J2EE application, but I am not clear how to have CDI provide the needed dependencies:

The current setup is quite simple/easy to understand:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyApplication  {


    @Inject
    @Named("Default")
    private Dependency dependency;

    public void dostuff(){
        dependency.process();
    }

}
```

I now need a new instance of `dependency` each time I call `dostuff`.

I am unclear on how to use CDI to create this for me. My Dependency has its own dependencies that I would like CDI to create for me.

I expect there is a layer of indirection I need to add.

Additional context: 
This class is part of a process that polls for work to be done, and is hosted in Wildfly.
We are not using Spring in the project.

Comment: Method invocation boundaries do not correspond to any of the standard managed bean scopes.  I'm not sure that scuttles your idea completely, since it is possible to define custom scopes, but it may be quicker and easier to go a different direction.

Comment: *Interceptors* seem better suited to per-method-invocation action, but it's not immediately clear to me how you would leverage them to obtain the behavior you require.

Comment: What is the scope of  `Dependency`? If it is `@Dependent`, then injecting an `Instance<Dependency>` will accomplish what you want - JUST REMEMBER TO CALL `Instance.destroy()` IN A `finally` BLOCK, OR MEMORY LEAKS WILL OCCUR. There may be other solutions, if you could describe the problem and its constraints in more detail.

Comment: Functionally,  I want the Dependency to have a scope similar to that of the requestScope. BUT, since "owning class"  parent class has a larger scope, It  is not easily done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you desire is having a new instance of `Dependency`, each time the method is called, I think what you need is an instance of `Provider` that is (`javax.inject.Provider<T>`) injected in your class/`bean`.

Inject the provider to your current class:

```
@Inject Provider<DesiredBean> provider;
```

Then, in your method `doStuff()` obtain the new instance:

```
DesiredBean desiredBean = provider.get();
```

This should get you going.

Comment: when using Provider<T>, I assume I need to also use something similar to CDI.current().destroy(desiredBean ); to cleanup objects or EntityManager It has, or any of it's dependencies have?

Comment: As per my personal experience/use, I have never destroyed the obtained bean. So I cannot swear if you need to destroy it. However, since CDI implements `Provider<T>` interface and you desire a new instance always, there should not be any harm in destroying the instance using `CDI.current().destory(desiredBean)`.

Comment: Is there any way to use this technique with `@Inject` `@Any` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need to use CDI besides the dependency injection?

If not, I'd suggest making doStuff() take a Dependency object as a parameter:

```
public void doStuff(Dependency dependency) {
  dependency.process();
}
```

Then, when you call the method, you provide it with a new instance of Dependency:

```
myApplication.doStuff(new Dependency());
```

That way, you are still keeping your class less coupled than declaring a new instance in the constructor or field.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

The main reason is that my Dependency has dal objects, and container managed EntityManagers ect. It could be changed, but it would be non-trivial.

Other fun facts: Dependency is an interface, and it's concrete classes figure out what dependencies it should have baed on context/database information.

It is not core to my problem, except to say, I'd rather avoid doing that is possible.

I may need to think about this if CDI is not up to the task.